# Can't connect to a redis-server running on a virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

On the virtual machine, my netstat is:

```
$ netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:6767                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:35478                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:8000                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:45424              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

When I try to connect from my host machine, I get:

```
$ redis-cli -h 192.168.33.10 -p 6379
Could not connect to Redis at 192.168.33.10:6379: Connection refused
```

Not sure what else to do. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but I'll ask it anyway: Can the host machine see the guest - 192.168.33.10 - at all? What are the machine OS'es? Is the firewall on that machine turned off? (iptables) Is the firewall on your host machine turned off? How are they connecting, e.g. host-only networking etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the service is listening on 127.0.0.1

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          *:*                     LISTEN
```

Comment: Why is this? In my `redis.conf`, I commented out the `bind` line so I should be listening on all interfaces, no?

Comment: did you restart the service ?

Comment: Yuppers. I most certainly did.

Comment: maybe try to force to listen on the nic
"bind 192.168.33.10" or this "bind 0.0.0.0"